# React-Native, Flipper, How to connect in adb wifi mode

Tags: react-native, flipper

I use adb's usb mode to sync between PC and device, flipper is working

But when I use the wifi mode of adb to synchronize between the PC and the device, the following error is reported:
[image]
I don't know how to solve it, hope to get your help.

Thanks.

---

** Environment**

- mac
- Flipper 0.147.1